# How to use unicode strings in python wrapping for c++ class with cython?

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am currently working on a pet-project. My goal now is to write a wrapper for c++ class to python with cython. The thing is that i have to work with russian text (unicode), but cython wrapping takes only bytes, despite of c++ class method, that are capable of process unicode string properly. I read Cython documentation and tried to find it in google, but found nothing.

How can i change my code, so my python wrapper could take unicode strings?

Here is a link to my github repo with the current code files
https://github.com/rproskuryakov/lemmatizer/tree/trie

"trie.pxd"

```py
from libcpp.string cimport string
from libcpp cimport bool

cdef extern from "Trie.cpp":
    pass

# Declare the class with cdef
cdef extern from "Trie.h": 
    cdef cppclass Trie:
        Trie() except +
        void add_word(string word)  # function that should take unicode
        bool find(string word)  # function that should take unicode
```

"pytrie.pyx"

```py
from trie cimport Trie  # link to according .pxd file

# Create a Cython extension type which holds a C++ instance
# as an attribute and create a bunch of forwarding methods
# Python extension type.
cdef class PyTrie:
    cdef Trie c_tree # Hold a C++ instance which we're wrapping

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.c_tree = Trie()

    def add_word(self, word): 
        return self.c_tree.add_word(word) 

    def find(self, word): 
        return self.c_tree.find(word)
```

Here is what i get in python.

```py
>>> tree.add_word(b'hello') # works if i got english into ascii
>>> tree.add_word(b'привет') # doesnt work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "wrapper/pytrie.pyx", line 13, in pytrie.PyTrie.add_word
  File "stringsource", line 15, in string.from_py.__pyx_convert_string_from_py_std__in_string
TypeError: expected bytes, str found
```

Comment: I'm surprised there is such a thing as `b'привет'`, I thought bytes would contain only ASCII literal characters....

Comment: Exactly, 'привет' is not ascii and function can't take it, but i need to.

Comment: When I type `a=b'привет'` in my Python-interpreter I get an error, because bytes can contain only ASCII literals (Python3.7), I'm not sure which Python version you are using, that it works for you (`u'привет'` would work, but it is not what your are doing).

Comment: Maybe you should add, that you still using Python2, which by now is no longer "default".

Comment: I use python 3.6, and tree.add_word('hello') or tree.add_word('привет'), tree.add_word(u'привет') return the same error.

Answer (score 3):

C++ strings are internally a `char` array, so really operate on a "bytes" level rather than a unicode level. Therefore Cython doesn't automatically support a `unicode/str` <-> `std::string` conversion. However, you have two fairly simple options:

1. Use the `unicode/str.encode` function to get a bytes representation of the unicode object:

   ```
   def add_word(self, word):
       if isinstance(word,str): # Python3 version - use unicode for Python 2
           word = word.encode()
       return self.c_tree.add_word(word)
   ```

   The main thing you have to be careful of is that the encoding that C++ uses to interpret it is the same as Python uses to encode it (Python uses utf8 by default).
2. Convert to the C++ type `std::wstring` - internally an array of `wchar_t`. Unfortunately Cython doesn't wrap `wstring` by default or provide automatic conversions, and therefore you'll need to write your own wrapper. Use the [Cython wrapping of `std::string`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libcpp/string.pxd) as a reference - you may well only need to wrap the constructors anyway. I've used [the Python C API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsWideChar) for the conversion to a `wchar_t*`.

   ```
   from libc.stddef cimport wchar_t

   cdef extern from "<string>" namespace std:
       cdef cppclass wstring:
           wstring() except +
           wstring(size_t, wchar_t) except +

           const wchar_T* data()

   cdef extern from "Python.h":
        # again, not wrapped by cython a s adefault
        Py_ssize_t PyUnicode_AsWideChar(object o, wchar_t *w, Py_ssize_t size) except -1

   # conversion function
   cdef wstring to_wstring(s):
       # create 0-filled output
       cdef wstring out = wstring(len(s),0)
       PyUnicode_AsWideChar(s, <wchar_t*>out.data(),len(s)) # note cast to remove const 
        # I'm not convinced this is 100% acceptable according the standard but practically it should work
       return out
   ```

Which of these options your prefer largely depends on what your C++ accepts for unicode strings.